# None of the nvidia drivers works on ubuntu 4.15 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a Asus GT 1030 Nvidia graphics card.

I tried all the nvidia drivers, including

```
 nvidia-390 nvidia-410 and nvidia-415
```

I install each one with apt-get and then reboot, but the reboot goes to blank screen, and I have to go to go to root and purge nvidia* to make it start again.

The display manager is gdm3.

After installing any driver, it shows success, but

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

shows nothing.

Any idea what needs to be done here?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Secure Boot? If so it might prevent the Nvidia drivers to load. You can try disabling it in the boot menu.

You could try the nouveau.modeset boot option as well, just press 'e' while in grub-menu and add `nouveau.modeset=0` after the line which starts with "linux" then press f10.